# Helium written in Go

Tags: go

Help me with code code review.
Helium is my pet project, written in Golang.
Helium is a small, simple, modular constructor with some pre-built components.

https://github.com/im-kulikov/helium

Simple example how to use it

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "github.com/im-kulikov/helium"
    "github.com/im-kulikov/helium/grace"
    "github.com/im-kulikov/helium/logger"
    "github.com/im-kulikov/helium/module"
    "github.com/im-kulikov/helium/settings"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

var mod = module.New(newApp).
    Append(
        settings.Module,
        logger.Module,
        grace.Module)

// App struct
type App struct {
    v *viper.Viper
}

func newApp(v *viper.Viper) helium.App {
    return &App{v: v}
}

// Run application
func (a App) Run(ctx context.Context) error {
    spew.Dump(a.v.AllSettings())

    return nil
}

func main() {
    h, err := helium.New(&helium.Settings{
        Prefix:       "demo",
        Name:         "demo",
        BuildTime:    "now",
        BuildVersion: "dev",
    }, mod)
    helium.Catch(err)
    helium.Catch(h.Run())
}
```

Comment: "Helium is a small, simple, modular constructor" – Excuse my ignorance, but *what* does it construct?

Comment: It’s provide simple way to build application in simple ways.. or make fast prototype of feature application..

Comment: If you want Helium to be reviewed, you'll have to copy the content of it to the actual question. Embed it directly. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

A little detail; in `Run`:

```
// Run application
func (a App) Run(ctx context.Context) error {
    spew.Dump(a.v.AllSettings())

    return nil
}
```

`error` will be always null. 
And according [go-spew/spew#Dump](https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew#Dump);

> `func Dump(a ...interface{})`

`Dump` doesn't return a thing.
So seems like you should be able to a.- remove `error`from your signature, or b.- do some sanity check on `a.v` to see, for example, that those elements are not nil/etc.

Comment: That may be true fror this particular implementation, `spew.Dump`, but it is not necessarily true for all implementations. Therefore, it is not a good idea. Keep the general API form and return `error`.

Comment: I see! should be better then add some sanity checks? and when you say 'general api form' do you know if there is a specification, design or something about that? (it makes sense, but it bothers me a little bit the error always being nil :D). thanks for your time, btw.

Comment: That’s was just an example.. in other ways in run can be errors